# I have used query datetimepicker for selecting date and time, working in chrome but not in firefox mozilla

Tags: jquery, html, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

Used Bootstrap Datetimepicker in a html field using field Id for selecting date and time.

when i was selecting dateTime in google chrome it is working fine but in firefox it is selecting as "-2019-09-11 08:25". It automatically add "-" before dateTime.

```
$('#time_to').datetimepicker({ weekStart: 1, clearBtn: 1, autoclose: 1, todayHighlight: 1, startView: 1, forceParse: 0, showMeridian: 1, maxView: 1, startDate: new Date($("#PostingDate").val() + " 00:00"), endDate: new Date($("#PostingDate").val() + " 23:59") }).prop('disabled', true);
```

Expected Output will be:

> "-2019-09-11 08:25"

But actual Output is:

> "2019-09-11 08:25"

Comment: sorted!!!just removed the space before the time "23:59" and it will work for me.

Comment: Used function and define date format because in google chrome date format is different and in mozilla used different  date format. use user define-function dateformatter before "($("#PostingDate").val()"